# Difference between 2 datetimes in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, datetime

my table's schema is something like

```
Table A
Id | val | updatedtime
```

Where updatedtime column is of the type Datetime,

I need to find all the records from db where the time difference between current time and updatedtime of the db is less than 5 min. I couldn't find any right approach on the internet

Comment: I've changed the title because SQL Server has an unfortunately named (though thankfully the name is deprecated) type called `timestamp` that has nothing to do with dates and times.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like such?

```
SELECT *
FROM TableA
WHERE updatetime > DATEADD(MI, -5, GETDATE())
```

Comment: Why would you choose to subtract 300 seconds rather than 5 minutes?

Comment: Because;
SELECT DATEDIFF(MI, '2000-01-01 00:00:00', '2000-01-01 00:05:10')

Comment: But `DATEADD(minute,-5,'2000-01-01T00:05:10)` produces `2000-01-01T00:00:10`. `DATEADD` preserves the smaller components.

Comment: And now I can upvote because your query at least allows indexes to still be used.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45463/discussion-between-markd-and-damien-the-unbeliever)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM TableA
WHERE DATEDIFF(minute,updatedtime,GETDATE()) < 5
```

Yo can use **[DATEDIFF](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx)**

> Returns the count (signed integer) of the specified datepart
>   boundaries crossed between the specified startdate and enddate

Comment: Well in this case this kind of error is expected.."Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
"

Comment: Your query will negate indexes on updatedtime. SARG.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below SQL

```
SELECT *
FROM YourTable
WHERE (DateDiff(mi, updatetime, GETDATE())) < 5
```